# How to set border left and right of button using before?

Tags: html, css, border

How to set border left and right of button using only one :before or :after with 20px space left and right side of button, What i tried to set border see attachment of design - what i want. Please help me by my screenshot. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```css
.btn-action {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical!important;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal!important;
  -ms-flex-direction: column!important;
  flex-direction: column!important;
  display: -webkit-box!important;
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: flex!important;
  -webkit-box-pack: center!important;
  -ms-flex-pack: center!important;
  justify-content: center!important;
  -webkit-box-align: center!important;
  -ms-flex-align: center!important;
  align-items: center!important;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 32px;
  border: 2px solid #C3A165;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s all;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s all;
}
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #C3A165;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #C3A165;
}
.btn:before {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #C3A165;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 25px;
}
.border {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="btn-action">
  <div class="border">
    <a href="#" class="btn primary">Get Started</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use both `:before` and `:after` for left and right line respectively.

```css
.btn-action {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical!important;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal!important;
  -ms-flex-direction: column!important;
  flex-direction: column!important;
  display: -webkit-box!important;
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: flex!important;
  -webkit-box-pack: center!important;
  -ms-flex-pack: center!important;
  justify-content: center!important;
  -webkit-box-align: center!important;
  -ms-flex-align: center!important;
  align-items: center!important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 32px;
  border: 2px solid #C3A165;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s all;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s all;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #C3A165;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #C3A165;
}

.btn:before {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #C3A165;
  width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1040px;
  top: 25px;
}

.btn:after {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #C3A165;
  width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -1040px;
  top: 25px;
}

.border {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="btn-action">
  <div class="border">
    <a href="#" class="btn primary">Get Started</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since only one pseudo element is allowed, you can use `box-shadow` to achieve the effect. However the position values have to be hardcoded.

```css
.btn-action {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical!important;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal!important;
  -ms-flex-direction: column!important;
  flex-direction: column!important;
  display: -webkit-box!important;
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: flex!important;
  -webkit-box-pack: center!important;
  -ms-flex-pack: center!important;
  justify-content: center!important;
  -webkit-box-align: center!important;
  -ms-flex-align: center!important;
  align-items: center!important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 32px;
  border: 2px solid #C3A165;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s all;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s all;
}
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #C3A165;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #C3A165;
}
.btn:before {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#C3A165 30%,transparent 30% 70%,#C3A165 70% 100%);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 25px;
}
.border {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="btn-action">
  <div class="border">
    <a href="#" class="btn primary">Get Started</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Another method is to use `linear-gradient`

```css
.btn-action {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical!important;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal!important;
  -ms-flex-direction: column!important;
  flex-direction: column!important;
  display: -webkit-box!important;
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: flex!important;
  -webkit-box-pack: center!important;
  -ms-flex-pack: center!important;
  justify-content: center!important;
  -webkit-box-align: center!important;
  -ms-flex-align: center!important;
  align-items: center!important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 32px;
  border: 2px solid #C3A165;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s all;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s all;
}
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #C3A165;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #C3A165;
}
.btn:before {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#C3A165 30%,transparent 30% 70%,#C3A165 70% 100%);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 25px;
}
.border {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="btn-action">
  <div class="border">
    <a href="#" class="btn primary">Get Started</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply this css may be this you are looking for

```
.btn {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 24px;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 12px 32px;
      border: 2px solid #C3A165;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 500;
      background-color: transparent;
      border-radius: 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: 0.3s all;
      -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
      -moz-transition: 0.3s all;
      -ms-transition: 0.3s all;
      z-index:2;
    }
    .btn:hover {
      background-color: #C3A165;
      color: #fff;
      border-color: #C3A165;
    }
    .btn:before {
      content: '';
      height: 1px;
      background-color: #C3A165;
      width: 35%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 25px;
      z-index:1;
    }
    .btn:after {
      content: '';
      height: 1px;
      background-color: #C3A165;
      width: 35%;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 25px;
      z-index:1;
    }
    .border {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
```